# Is the pronunciation of す /sɨ/ or /sɯ/?

Tags: pronunciation

The wiki says on 2 separate occasions that it should be /sɨ/, see the pages for [Japanese phonology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_phonology) and [Gojyuuon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goj%C5%ABon).

However, when the endings such as です・ます are pronounced without the reduction of that vowel, it sounds a lot like /sɯ/. See these bits from forvo: [行きます](https://audio00.forvo.com/mp3/9498333/76/9498333_76_1595081.mp3), [食べます](https://audio00.forvo.com/mp3/9699293/76/9699293_76_2274341.mp3), [です](https://audio00.forvo.com/mp3/9677061/76/9677061_76_13709.mp3), [～です](https://audio00.forvo.com/mp3/9498333/76/9498333_76_5360005.mp3)

Here's my attempt at replicating what /sɨ/ would sound like in comparison to /sɯ/: https://voca.ro/1mThRUHgiEJW (/sɯ/ followed by /sɨ/).

The sound /ɨ/ exists in my native language so I was quite surprised to see that it exists in japanese as well, and in す no less, which I have never heard about. And as you can see from my recording, /sɨ/ sounds very off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [a dictionary](http://daijirin.dual-d.net/extra/nihongoon.html), it is /sɯ̈/ (with the dots on it).

I'm not an expert, but according to quick searches:

There is a phenomenon called 中舌化, quoting from [here](https://japaneselanguageinstructorload.at.webry.info/200904/article_2.html)

> 日本語の「ウ」は単独で発音すると非円唇後舌狭母音である。
> しかし、「ス・ツ・ズ（ヅ）」のように舌先で発音される子音の後に
> 続くときは下の盛り上がりの位置が前にずれて中舌よりになる。
> これを母音の中舌化という。

Probably this is why /sɨ/ is used in the tables of your link. But I guess the vowel is not completely centralized in general, and /sɨ/ sounds too different from す because of it.

[This articles](https://museum.ninjal.ac.jp/area/post-428.html) mentions /sɨ/ for す as well, but the sounds do not really sound like /sɨ/ to me.

===

[Tohoku dialects](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9D%B1%E5%8C%97%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80) tend not to differentiate し and す:

> イ段とウ段の母音は中舌母音[ï]・[ɯ̈]で発音される。このうち「し」対「す」、「ち」対「つ」およびその濁音「じ」対「ず」（「ぢ」対「づ」）は大半の地域で区別がなく、

===

The pronunciation of Russian сын is written as スィーン in a dictionary at hand.

Comment: This happens with IPA. I’m not convinced that the consonant of に is the same as the sound represented by the letter *ñ* in Spanish, although they are both transcribed with the symbol [ɲ]. The degree of palatalization seems significantly greater in the latter.

Comment: The dots on /sɯ̈/ mean centralization (which is presumably what 中舌化 also means), so this should read /sʉ/ in conventional IPA. Not sure why that page decided to not use this symbol, even though it's on their vowel chart

Comment: @maritsm: [ʉ] is the central equivalent of the rounded [u]. The Japanese う is the unrounded [ɯ].

Comment: Indeed, I meant to write /sɨ/, which is the central equivalent of /ɯ/